# Textbox - horizontal text centering

Tags: wpf, text, textbox, centering

Is there any simple way to center a text in textbox? I was looking for some built-in functions, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 80):

Set the `TextAlignment` property to `Center`:

```
<TextBox Width="200"
         Text="Hello world !"
         TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for repy but it didn't work. However You gave me path which  I followed and I used sth like this in my style

    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>

HorizontalContentAlignment didn't work but code above did the trick.
However another problem occured. Namely now if I click right mouse button on my textbox text in contextMenu is centered :(

Comment: Oh, I see... actually you should use only TextAlignment, not HorizontalContentAlignment

Answer (score 65):

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
```

Comment: This answer did not work for me, however setting the TextAlignment property did.

Answer (score 7):

You can reach the text within a WPF-TextBox with the combination VerticalAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment. 
You set the content to center and the total height with Stretch to the size of the comprehensive element like a grid row

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"> 
Test 
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 6):

it's too late but this may be helpful for someone

Try adding this two peoperties to your control

```
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" >
```

VerticalAlignment = "Center" and padding 
You can reach the text within a WPF-TextBox with the combination VerticalAlignment and Padding. 
Like VerticalAlignment = "Center" Padding = "5" 
Padding causes the text field to become larger and adapt to the surrounding element.

[image: The Image Shows a Output]

Answer (score 3):

```
<TextBox Width="200" Text="Hello world !" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

VerticalContentAlignment sets the Alignment for the Text in a Textbox

Comment: This appears to repeat other answers. A new answer to an old question should give new and useful information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom ControlTemplate, you need to change the ScrollViewer (`x:Name="PART_ContentHost"`) to have `VerticalAlignment="Center"`. (In addition to setting VerticalAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment on the TextBox itself as described in other answers.)

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```